# Kentico CMS: Log searches made by visitors within my site

Tags: search, logging, content-management-system, kentico

I have a search box web part on my Kentico site.

Is there a way to see what visitors are searching for within my site?

maybe a log of all the searches made, within the Site Manager somewhere?

If this information doesn't exist by default is there a way to gather this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in version 6 released in October 2011. It allows you to track keywords used in the on-site search using the Kentico Web Analytics module (see report Content -> On-site search keywords).

There's also another report showing keywords used in the search engine (Google, etc.) before the customer came to your website (Traffic sources -> Search keywords).

Another way how to track the search keywords (and much more) is using Kentico EMS - it tracks on-site search as a visitor activity that can later be used for personalization, segmentation or lead scoring.